# Call Wordpress Page into CMS page with Fishpig extension

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know the proper code to load a Page from Wordpress into a CMS page using the Fishpig extension? I have seen postings regarding how to load Posts from Wordpress but nothing about Pages.

Comment: I don´t have an answer but have you tried contacting Ben from Fishpig, he usually gets back to you with a really good help and even would help you to fix it if you have problems. At least that´s my experience in the past.

Answer (score 2):

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/root/

This extension will allow you to bring in whole pages from fishpig.